# wcsncat_s show error assertion string is not null terminated

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to append char. after succeful compile it show error assertion failure.

> L"string is not null terminated. line 124

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <string>

int main(){
    wchar_t jszProcessName[4096];
    wcsncat_s(jszProcessName, L"iloveyou", 1000);

    wcout << jszProcessName;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Not only is there no question here but there is no line 124. The compiler told you precisely what was wrong. But you ignored the error message. Was it really easier to ask here than to simply read the compiler error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your uninitialized array probably doesn't have a value of `0` which is what the  [wcsncat_s](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/wide/wcsncat) function expects. Either [zero initialize](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) the array first:

```
wchar_t jszProcessName[4096] = {};
```

or set the first element to a null terminator character:

```
jszProcessName[0] = L'\0';
```

which is equivalent to an integral value of `0`:

```
jszProcessName[0] = 0;
```

Without it your `wcsncat_s` function invokes [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: The wide-char nul character is `L'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

Set the first character of your target array to 0. `wcsncat_s` **appends** to a character string; that means it looks for the terminating null at the end of the string, and copies the new text at that point. If there is no terminating null your program goes off into lala-land.